Get data points from a graph and close modal inside shadow root
I am trying to scrape the graph on the website: https://www.xe.com/currencycharts/?from=SGD&to=USD&view=5Y
First I tried to fetch the data via a network request: how to fetch data from dynamic graph in python which didn't work.
Now I am trying to move the cursor to the graph element and move across it horizontally, I am able to successfully fetch the data points, but I am facing the following issues:
1- The cursor starts to move from the middle of the element, not the start of it. I have also tried to move it via coordinates, but got "Element out of bound" error. It works fine and then near the end, it mostly throws the "Element out of bound" error.
2- A modal appears on top of the graph sometimes, which I am unable to close as the close button for it is located inside #shadow-root element.
I have tried the following code to try to fetch the data points and close the modal:

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

BASE_DIR = os.getcwd()


chrome_path = which("chromedriver")
options = Options()
currentDirectory = os.getcwd()
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
# options.add_argument('--headless')
service = Service(executable_path=chrome_path)
wait_time = 20
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument', {'source': """
Element.prototype._attachShadow = Element.prototype.attachShadow;
Element.prototype.attachShadow = function () {
    return this._attachShadow( { mode: "open" } );
};
"""})
# Load the website
driver.get('https://www.xe.com/currencycharts/?from=SGD&to=USD&view=5Y')
try:
    driver.maximize_window()
except:
    pass
# Wait for the page to fully load (add explicit waits if needed)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)


element = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[@class='recharts-wrapper']")       
element_width = element.size['width']
actions = ActionChains(driver)
time.sleep(1)
try:
    accept_cookies_button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[@class='sc-fe840e0c-0 kpuPwJ']")       
    accept_cookies_button.click()
except:
    pass
# Move across the element with 10 px increments horizontally
# for x_offset in range(0, element_width, 10):
#     actions.move_to_element_with_offset(element, x_offset, 0).perform()
ad_form_found = False
for x_offset in range(1, element_width, 10):
    if not ad_form_found:
        try:
            close_ad_form = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[@id='yie-overlay-wrapper-fe8ec9fc-c476-5739-bef4-7a89b6181df9']/yld-tag-host-campaign")       
            if close_ad_form:
                print('CLOSE AD FORM FOUND')
                shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', close_ad_form)
                # close_ad_button = shadow_root.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[@id='element-Rrwwg7']")       
                close_ad_button = shadow_root.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="button[id^='element']")
                if close_ad_button:
                    print("close ad button found")
                    ad_form_found = True
                close_ad_button.click()
        except:
            pass
    actions.move_to_element_with_offset(element, x_offset, 1).perform()
    # paragraph_elements = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[@class='recharts-tooltip-wrapper recharts-tooltip-wrapper-left recharts-tooltip-wrapper-bottom']/div/p")       
    paragraph_elements = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[@class='recharts-tooltip-wrapper recharts-tooltip-wrapper-right recharts-tooltip-wrapper-bottom']/div/p")       
    for paragraph in paragraph_elements:
        print(paragraph.text)

    time.sleep(0.1)
# Close the browser
driver.quit()


I get the "CLOSE AD FORM FOUND" print in the terminal, but it is unable to find the "X" button inside the form to close it.
Here is a picture of the browser window:

I found the code for interacting with shadow root from the following question: How to locate element in shadow-root (closed) host
The script basically stays still after this modal appears and a while later, the script closes with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 117, in <module>
    actions.move_to_element_with_offset(element, x_offset, 1).perform()

selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds

The cursor moves from the middle of the element instead of the start and it stops around 25 Oct 2023 (roughly)



maybe the Rrwwg7 part is random. if it is, this may work (by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="button[id^='element']")

I have made try and error on this subject and succeeded to get the latest data with the following code.
Because to get the elements by
"//div[@class='recharts-tooltip-wrapper recharts-tooltip-wrapper-right recharts-tooltip-wrapper-bottom']/div/p"

was frequentry failed, I tried without "/div/p", as
tooltip = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^= 'recharts-tooltip-wrapper']")
paragraph_elements = tooltip.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"p")
for p in paragraph_elements:
    print (p.text)

But with this code, a "stale" exception encountered after the first text of the two p elements. It shows that the inner HTML stays during very short time. My solution is to get inner HTML and parse it afterwords by lxml.
When the mouse position comes over the graph range, the return value of "innerHTML" comes null, where the code stops the process(actually after continual two times of null return). It is far before the border over which "OutOfBoundsException" is evoked.
Because of the purpose of "close_ad_form", it needs not waiting time, and "implicitly_wait" only makes the process slower. To have removed this contributes the process to run faster.
As to the modal, I added WebDriverWait after the shadow root is got, with which I have succeeded once. But because modal has not appeared during my testing, it was not assured whether the code for this part is effective or not.
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which
from selenium import webdriver
from  time import sleep
import os
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

import lxml.html

BASE_DIR = os.getcwd()

chrome_path = which("chromedriver")
options = Options()
currentDirectory = os.getcwd()
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
# options.add_argument('--headless')
service = Service(executable_path=chrome_path)
#wait_time = 20
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument', {'source': """
Element.prototype._attachShadow = Element.prototype.attachShadow;
Element.prototype.attachShadow = function () {
    return this._attachShadow( { mode: "open" } );
};
"""})
# Load the website
driver.get('https://www.xe.com/currencycharts/?from=SGD&to=USD&view=5Y')
try:
    driver.maximize_window()
except:
    pass
# Wait for the page to fully load (add explicit waits if needed)
#driver.implicitly_wait(5)

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    ( By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='recharts-wrapper']"   ) ))
element_width = element.size['width']
actions = ActionChains(driver)

try:
    accept_cookies_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//button[@class='sc-fe840e0c-0 kpuPwJ']")  )) 
    accept_cookies_button.click()
except:
    pass

# Move across the element with 10 px increments horizontally
ad_form_found = False
for x_offset in range(0, element_width, 10):
    if not ad_form_found:
        try:
            close_ad_form =  WebDriverWait(driver, 0.5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, "//div[@id='yie-overlay-wrapper-fe8ec9fc-c476-5739-bef4-7a89b6181df9']/yld-tag-host-campaign") ))
        except:
            pass
        else:
            print('CLOSE AD FORM FOUND')
            #shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', close_ad_form)
            shadow_root = close_ad_form.shadow_root
            # close_ad_button = shadow_root.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[@id='element-Rrwwg7']")       
            #close_ad_button = shadow_root.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="button[id^='element']")
            close_ad_button= WebDriverWait(shadow_root, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id^='element']")))
            if close_ad_button:
                print("close ad button found")
                ad_form_found = True
                close_ad_button.click()
    try:
        actions.move_to_element_with_offset(element, x_offset, 1).perform()
        
    except:#OutOfBoundsException
        print('exception')
        break
    else: 
        
        for i in range(2):#repeat for occasional missing innerHTML 
            print('\n')
            actions.move_to_element_with_offset(element, x_offset, 1).perform()#
            tooltip = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^= 'recharts-tooltip-wrapper']")
            inner = tooltip.get_attribute('innerHTML')
            print('innerHTML:  ', tooltip.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
            if inner != "":
                #paragraph_elements = tooltip.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"p") #this may cause "stale" exception.
                p_root = lxml.html.fromstring(inner)
                p_elements = p_root.xpath("//p")
                for p in p_elements:
                    print (p.text)
                break
            else:
                pass
        else:
            break

    sleep(0.1)

a= input('To close this session input any key ')
    

